# Make menu and image appear on the same line

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to make my menu and image appear on the same line but sadly that doesn't seem to be happening. Could anyone tell me why and how I would solve my problem? I've got the following image and menu...

HTML

```
        <div id="header">

        <img alt="" height="67" src="Aidanlogo.png" width="400" />
        <div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br style="clear: left" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Menu CSS: http://pastebin.com/drMD7gwg

Header CSS

```
  #header {
width: 700px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#menu ul li { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Divs are block elements, so by default it will always appear on a separate line.

You could make the image a block and float it left (`display:block; float:left;`)

You could make your div `display:inline-block`, or `float:right;` it, assuming there's room in the parent (700px).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`DIV` is a block element, so it won't display on the same line as anything else unless you change it's `inline` property:

```
#myslidemenu { display:inline; }
```

Also note that you'll have to modify the `<ul>` styles to display the `<li>` tags on a single line. [See this link for more on that part](http://www.secondpicture.com/tutorials/web_design/css_ul_li_horizontal_css_menu.html).

**edit** I'm not sure what the jQuery slide menu does to the `<div>` or `<ul>` styles - you might have a look in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) after it's rendered.